# MySQL Query on table with 23m rows sometimes hangs and causes slow down

Tags: mysql

I have a web service built using PHP/Laravel. One of the tables a query is being formed on contains over 23 million rows.

One of the queries, most of the time executes fine. However sometimes when I look at the clients connections via MySQLWorkbench, I see that there are a group of queries which appear to be stuck. When this happens, future executions of the same query slow down and CPU usage on the database increases.

I don't seem to be able to replicate the issue manually, nor am I able to replicate the issue by using the mobile application which consumes data from the API, all the queries complete in reasonable time and successfully.

When I look at MySQLWorkbench this is what I see;

[image]

The query being executed is;

```
SELECT af.*, a.name, a.picture AS profile_picture
FROM artist_feeds AS af
STRAIGHT_JOIN user_artists AS ua ON ua.artist_id = af.artist_id
STRAIGHT_JOIN artists AS a ON a.id = af.artist_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN user_artist_disabled_networks AS uadn
    ON uadn.user_id = ua.user_id AND uadn.socialnetwork_id = af.socialnetwork_id
WHERE af.feed_date >= '2010-10-29'
    AND uadn.user_id IS NULL
    AND ua.user_id = 498
ORDER BY af.feed_date DESC
LIMIT 0, 20
```

EXPLAIN shows the following;

[image]

The response from SHOW CREATE TABLE is;

```
CREATE TABLE `artist_feeds` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `feed_id` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `feed_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `message` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `hash` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `source` mediumtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `picture` mediumtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `link` mediumtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `artist_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `socialnetwork_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `direct_link` mediumtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `is_master_feed` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
  `active` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `rss_feed_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `artist_id` (`artist_id`),
  KEY `socialnetwork_id` (`socialnetwork_id`),
  KEY `feedidnetwork` (`feed_id`(191),`socialnetwork_id`),
  KEY `feeddatenetworkid` (`feed_date`,`socialnetwork_id`),
  KEY `feeddatenetworkidartistid` (`artist_id`,`socialnetwork_id`,`feed_date`),
  KEY `type` (`type`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=26991713 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Does anyone have any ideas why this query is occassionally getting 'stuck'? I'm assuming it's 'stuck' doing something, as once you have 5 of these queries 'stuck', the response time of the database slows down and CPU usage increases.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `STRAIGHT JOIN`?  Let the optimizer do its work.

I would write the query like this:

```
SELECT af.*, a.name, a.picture AS profile_picture
FROM user_artists ua JOIN
     artist_feeds af
     ON ua.artist_id = af.artist_id JOIN
     artists a
     ON a.id = af.artist_id
     user_artist_disabled_networks uadn LEFT JOIN
     ON uadn.user_id = ua.user_id AND
        uadn.socialnetwork_id = af.socialnetwork_id
WHERE af.feed_date >= '2010-10-29' AND
      uadn.user_id IS NULL
      ua.user_id = 498
ORDER BY af.feed_date DESC
LIMIT 0, 20
```

My first inclination is for a join on `user_artists(user_id, artist_id)`, `user_feeds(artist_id, feed_date)`, and `user_artist_disabled_networks(user_id, socialnetwork_id)`.

Comment: Hi Gordon, I'm having the use STRAIGHT JOIN to force MySQL to use artist_feeds as the first table accessed. If I don't do that, then the query takes 30+ seconds to complete as it has to do the sorting using filesort. This issue of queries being 'stuck' also appeared before I started using STRAIGHT JOIN.